# Можно ли с помощью nltk анализировать смысл русского текста и выводить есть ли смысл в тексте или нет?

Tags: python, nltk

Можно ли с помощью nltk анализировать смысл русского текста и выводить есть ли смысл в тексте или нет?

Comment: Если коротко - нет, нельзя. В такой постановке задача вообще не может быть решена до создания полноценного сильного ИИ.

Comment: Сначала нужно определиться - что такое "смысл". Можно определить, написан ли текст вообще на русском языке, является ли он более-менее грамотным, из какой предметной области текст, на что он похож по стилю (вплоть до автора). Но смысл - понятие растяжимое. Приведите ваши примеры "бессмысленного текста" для начала.

Comment: задача выполнима если подготовить большой и заранее размеченный датасет. Т.е. обучающий набор данных, в котором будет присутствовать столбец с результатом. Тогда это обычная задача бинарной классификации.